# Cannot remove mysterious zero from beneath plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I've got five nice plots, but I've no idea why a `0` is printing beneath each. I've (at least tried) to remove x axis titles. I have **no code**--well, none I'm cognizant of--asking for the zeros beneath each x axis. I do wish to preserve the "SP22" etc. Here's the code for two of my plots:

```
output1 <- ggplot(data=SP22_SP23, aes(x=semesters, y=UG_classif, group=1)) +
  geom_line( aes(y=UG_classif), color="mediumaquamarine")+
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("SP22", "SUM22", "FA22", "SP23"), (expand = c(0,.1))) +
  scale_y_continuous(n.breaks = 10, limits = c(500, 3500)) +
    labs(title = "Undergraduate Enrollment:",
       subtitle= "Sp'22 through Sp'23\n", x = NULL, y = "Student Count") +
  theme_minimal() +
  removeGridX()

output2 <- ggplot(data=SP22_SP23, aes(x=semesters, y=NDseeking, group=1)) +
  geom_line( aes(y=NDseeking), color="tan3")+
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("SP22", "SUM22", "FA22", "SP23"), (expand = c(0,.1))) +
  scale_y_continuous(n.breaks = 10, limits = c(0, 400)) +
    labs(title = "Non-degree Seeking Enrollment:",
       subtitle= "Sp'22 through Sp'23\n", x=NULL, y = "Student Count") +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank()) +
  theme_minimal() +
  removeGridX()
```

And here's a screenshot of what I'm getting:

[image: plots with pesky zeros beneath]

As you can see, I've tried both putting `x = NULL` with the `labs()` and `theme(axis.title.x=element_blank())`.

Sincere thanks for any help!

Comment: Any alterations to a theme should happen after the theme, like `theme_minimal()`, is loaded, lest they be immediately overwritten by the theme.

Comment: Ahh yes! Thank you @JonSpring. But why doesn't "x=null" within the labs work? Thanks again

Comment: I have no idea why `NULL` turns into a zero, but I would try `x=""` (empty string) in `labs` instead.

Comment: Yea I am confused why it's a zero (of all things). Weird. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: It seems like a bug in something, but hard for anyone else to know if it's due to `ggExtra` (presumably where removeGridX is from) or any other loaded packages you might have. Can you reproduce it if you start a new session and just use plain ggplot2?

Comment: It would help to know that `removeGridX` is in `ggExtra` ...

Comment: I can't reproduce this with `ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) + labs(x=NULL) + theme_minimal() + ggExtra::removeGridX()`. Could we have a [mcve] please?

Comment: @JonSpring's suggestion to put `theme(axis.title.x=element_blank())` below theme worked. Thanks, all!

Comment: I'm still kind of curious why this happens in the first place ... do you get a zero with `x = ""` ... ?

Comment: remove the parenthesises around `(expand = c(0,.1))`

Comment: @BenBolker `x=""` still produced the pesky 0!

Comment: @BenBolker I learned just last week that `labs(x = NULL)` is generally nice because it removes the space allocated for the axis title. If you have `p = ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, hp)) + geom_point()`, compare `p + labs(x = "")` to `p + labs(x = NULL)` to see the difference in whitespace. (No clue on this question without a reproducible example.)

Comment: @user20650's deleted answer looks like the right track to me. The parentheses around `expand` tell R to print that parameter instead of using it as expected.  Compare `ggplot(mtcars, aes(as.character(cyl), mpg)) + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0.1))` to a version with `+ scale_x_discrete((expand = c(0, 0.1)))`.

Comment: Voting to undelete @user20650's answer ...

Comment: The reason that `(expand=c(0,0.1))` produces a name of 0 is that in your call to `scale_x_discrete`, the `(expand=..)` is a vector (with names) that is being passed without specifying the argument to which it should be assigned, and since it is the first (and only) unnamed argument to `scale_x_*`, it is assigned to the first argument, which is a `name=`. Since the first _value_ of that vector is `0`, so the name of the axis is set to `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `0` being printed is due to the `(expand = c(0,.1))` call in the `scale_x_discrete` call; the parenthesis is a short but to `print`ing. The zero in the axis is from the first value in the expand call.

To see:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) + scale_x_discrete((expand = c(2,3)))
```

Avoid this by not surrounding the `expand` argument by parenthesis.

e.g.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(2,3))
```